# Lisp - function that returns a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to create a function that receives 2 arguments and returns a function that receives himself a board. That function needs to check user input and make changes in the board according to the input. I have no problems with the user input and the changes i have to do to the board. My problem is with the function that returns a function. To do that i'm using a lambda. This is the code i'm working on:

```
(defun faz-jogador-manual (n_aneis peca)
#'(lambda (tabuleiro)
    (setf jogada (le-posicao))
    (let ((num_anel (first jogada))
        (posicao_anel (second jogada))
        (tab (copia-tabuleiro tabuleiro)))
    (tabuleiro-poe-peca tab peca num_anel posicao_anel))))
```

This function should return a function lambda, but when i call the function using:

```
(faz-jogador-manual 3 'X)
```

i get the following:

```
#<Closure (:INTERNAL FAZ-JOGADOR-MANUAL 0) [X] @ #x2112f462>
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, is it the call? is the function per se? I need help with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common Lisp is a Lisp-2, which means that it has a separate namespace for functions and values; as a result, functions need to be treated slightly specially in this case.  (This is in contrast to most Lisps.)

When you return a function as a value, you can't just invoke it in the same way as if you had defined it with `defun`.  You need to use `funcall` or `apply` to do so.  You can do it like this:

```
;; insert an appropriate argument in place of tabuleiro for the inner function
(funcall (faz-jogador-manual 3 'X) tabuleiro)
```

If you want to understand this behavior in more detail, you can probably find lots of references online, like [this one.](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html)

Comment: When trying to call the function with funcall as you said i get the following: Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `FAZ-JOGADOR-MANUAL'.

Comment: Yep, when calling the function like that, it actually works :) but i still get warnings when compiling, is there any way to fiz those problems, or i shouldn't care about that?

Comment: Warning: Free reference to undeclared variable JOGADA assumed special.

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro: You should use `let`, not `setf`, if `jogada` is intended to be a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Closure object is a lambda with lexical variables captured from the context (n_aneis and peca in your case). It's a value you can put into a variable or apply as a function with `funcall`.

```
(defvar closure (faz-jogador-manual 3 'X))
(funcall closure *table*)
```